# Удаление элемента из списка и БД

Tags: java, android, listview, sqlite

Есть простая БД, состоящая из одной таблицы в которой 2 колонки (_id, name);

В данный момент разбираюсь с удалением элементов ListView и удалением необходимой строчки в БД. Сама строчка из ListView удаляется, не могу пока понять как грамотно еще и из БД удалять то, что выбрал. Помогите пжлст.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "myDatabase.db";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "mainTable";
    private static final String COLUMN_NAME = "name";
    private static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";

    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table if not exists "
            + DATABASE_TABLE + " (_id integer primary key autoincrement,"
            + COLUMN_NAME + " text not null);";

    private static final int CM_DELETE_ID = 1;

    SQLiteDatabase myDatabase;

    ListView lv;
    SimpleAdapter sAdapter;
    ArrayList<Map<String, String>> data;
    Map<String, String> m;
    Cursor c;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        myDatabase = openOrCreateDatabase(DATABASE_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        myDatabase.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);

        // упаковываем данные в понятную для адаптера структуру
        data = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
        c = myDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] { COLUMN_ID, COLUMN_NAME }, null, null, null, null, null);

                //считываем данные с БД и заносим их в data
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
            m = new HashMap<String, String>();
            m.put(COLUMN_ID , String.valueOf(c.getInt(0)));
            m.put(COLUMN_NAME, c.getString(1));

            data.add(m);
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }

        // массив имен атрибутов, из которых будут читаться данные
        String[] from = { COLUMN_NAME };
        // массив ID View-компонентов, в которые будут вставлять данные
        int[] to = { R.id.tvText};

        // создаем адаптер
        sAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, data, R.layout.item, from, to);

        // определяем список и присваиваем ему адаптер
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvSimple);
        lv.setAdapter(sAdapter);
        registerForContextMenu(lv);

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                    int position, long id) {

                CharSequence text = ((TextView) v).getText();

                int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
                Context context = getApplicationContext();

                                **//КАК ПРАВИЛЬНО ВЫВЕСТИ id из БД?** (тут чушь)
                String where = " name = " + "'" + text + "'";

                c = myDatabase.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE,
                new String[] { "_id" }, where, null, null, null, null,
                        null);
                c.moveToFirst();

                CharSequence columnValue = String.valueOf(c.getInt(0));

                Toast.makeText(context, columnValue, duration).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
            ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {

        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        menu.add(0, CM_DELETE_ID, 0, "Удалить запись");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == CM_DELETE_ID) {
            // получаем инфу о пункте списка
            AdapterContextMenuInfo acmi = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item
                    .getMenuInfo();

            // удаляем Map из коллекции, используя позицию пункта в списке
               data.remove(acmi.position);
            // уведомляем, что данные изменились
               sAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                           myDatabase.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, COLUMN_ID + " = " **ЧТО  СЮДА ВПИСАТЬ???**,  null);

            return true;
        }
        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разобрался.
Сначала думал запоминать _id в tag пункта списка и по нему удалять записи.
Но есть более простой вариант, использовать **SimpleCursorAdapter** и не заморачиваться с запоминанием _id.

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == CM_DELETE_ID) {
        // получаем инфу о пункте списка
        AdapterContextMenuInfo acmi = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item
                .getMenuInfo();

           myDatabase.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, COLUMN_ID + " = " + acmi.id, null);
           cursor.requery();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}
```

Удаляется как item, так и запись из БД.